# Attachment page tag queries & posts not found

Tags: query, tags, attachments

My objective is to alter the main query using pre_get_posts so I can search only through attachments and only ones that have specific tags assigned to them. These tags are displayed to the user using the_tags().

The logic is in place so my attachments have tags and this is confirmed using var_dump on this attachment page template: http://photonew.rasdesignmedia.com/surf-kayaking-mark-woolward-a633257/

The problem is that when I click on the tag link outputted by the_tags(), no posts are found (http://photonew.rasdesignmedia.com/tag/surfing/). My function to alter the main query currently outputs the query so I can see what is going on. The tag/terms are there yet the query can find no posts.

I have tested a non-pre_get_posts version of this using twentyseventeen theme with no customization and I still no posts are returned.

I have flushed things out via settings > permalinks.

I am finding several other posts of similar topic but most were either resolve with a permalink reset or were CPT.

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

```
function search_attachment_post_type($query) {

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ($query->is_tag) {
            echo "This is a tag query. 404 Error is below the query dump.<br>";
            $query->set('post_type', 'attachment');
            $query->set('taxonomy', 'post_tag');
            echo '<pre>$query is set to post_type attachment and taxonomy to post_tag<br><br>'; var_dump($query); echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_attachment_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page isn't a 404, it's returning a status code 200. The title and body tags also indicate that the page is loading just fine.

A couple of things- there is no `taxonomy` argument. It would be redundant anyway, since the query already contains the queried taxonomy and term pulled from the parsed URL.

Your possible issue is outlined in [this note from the `WP_Query` Codex page under `type` parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters):

> `'attachment'` - an attachment. Whilst the default `WP_Query` `post_status` is `'publish'`, attachments have a default `post_status` of `'inherit'`. This means no attachments will be returned unless you also explicitly set `post_status` to `'inherit'` or `'any'`.

Comment: post_status set to 'inherit' in my pre_get_posts function did the trick. Thank you! As for the 404, you are also correct,...that was just embarrassing.